# Valgrind errors. Use of malloc and realloc in functions

Tags: c

I am trying to make mystrcat function to work. It seems to return right string but valgrind gives errors on my code which I cant seem to fix.

```
char *mystrcat(char *dest, const char *src) {
    int len = strlen(dest) * 2;
    char *origdest = realloc(dest, len);
    while(*dest) {
        dest++;
    }

    while (*src) {
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    return origdest; 
}

int main(void) {
    char *str = malloc(7);
    strcpy(str, "First");

    str = mystrcat(str, "Second");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
}
```

Valgrind errors which I don't understand:

```
==10== Invalid read of size 1
==10==    at 0x40068B: mystrcat (mystrcat.c:9)
==10==    by 0x40070F: main (mystrcat.c:25)
==10==  Address 0x5203040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 7 free'd
==10==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10==    by 0x40067B: mystrcat (mystrcat.c:8)
==10==    by 0x40070F: main (mystrcat.c:25)
==10==  Block was alloc'd at
==10==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10==    by 0x4006E6: main (mystrcat.c:22)
==10== 
==10== Invalid write of size 1
==10==    at 0x4006AF: mystrcat (mystrcat.c:14)
==10==    by 0x40070F: main (mystrcat.c:25)
==10==  Address 0x5203046 is 6 bytes inside a block of size 7 free'd
==10==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10==    by 0x40067B: mystrcat (mystrcat.c:8)
==10==    by 0x40070F: main (mystrcat.c:25)
==10==  Block was alloc'd at
==10==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10==    by 0x4006E6: main (mystrcat.c:22)
```

Comment: Check your sizes... `strlen(dest)` is 5, plus a string of 6 characters, plus the terminator. That's 12 characters. You allocate 5 * 2 (i.e. 10) bytes.

Comment: Talking about terminator, you don't add that to the `dest` string.

Comment: Lastly, `realloc` returns the *new* pointer. You still use `dest` as the destination when it should be the pointer returned by `realloc`.

Comment: Please edit your question and fix indention.

Answer (score 2):

You need this (see comments for explanations):

```
char *mystrcat(char *dest, const char *src) {
    int len = strlen(dest) * 2;
    char *newdest = realloc(dest, len);
    // newdest contains the pointer to the newly allocated memory
    // and dest is now no longer valid

    dest = newdest;
    while(*dest) {
        dest++;
    }

    // now dest points to the end of the string in the newly
    // allocated memory

    while (*src) {
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }

    // add NUL terminator
    *dest = 0;

    // we return the newly allocated memory
    return newdest;  
}
```

But this function is still not entirely correct.

This is wrong:

```
int len = strlen(dest) * 2;
```

Doubling the size is wrong, because if `src` is longer than the length of the `dest` string, there won't be enough memory and you'll get a buffer overflow.

The memory size needed for the concatenated string is:

`size of the original string + size of the string to be concatenated + 1`

The `+1` is needed because of the `NUL` string terminator.

You therefore need this:

```
int len = strlen(dest) + strlen(src) + 1;
```

And another thing:

```
char *mystrcat(char *dest, const char *src)
```

can be replaced by

```
char *mystrcat(const char *dest, const char *src)
```

because we actually don't modify the memory pointed by `dest`.

Be aware that your `mystrcat` only works if the destinatino pointer has been allocated with a `malloc`-like function.

Comment: Sorry, missed it. Commnet deleted.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean question edited for the `const` thanks, I will delete my comments, in a few minutes, you can delete yours too.

Comment: No, I was also wrong about the const. But you should have documented that dest must be allocated with malloc().

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean no, you were right about `const`. Answer anhanced as per your suggestion, thanks.